# Why can std::function<void(T)> get assigned to std::function<void(T const&)> but not std::function<void(T&)>?

Tags: c++, function, reference, arguments, constants

In this code snippet, I don't understand why there is an error below:

```cpp
#include <functional>

class Foo {};

int main()
{
    std::function<void(Foo)> func;

    std::function<void(Foo)> f1;
    std::function<void(Foo const&)> f2;
    std::function<void(Foo&)> f3;

    func = f1;
    func = f2;
    func = f3;  // error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::function<void(Foo)>’ and ‘std::function<void(Foo&)>’)

    return 0;
}
```

So, I'm wondering why is it OK to use a function taking the parameter by constant reference, but not as a non-constant reference?

Can somebody kindly explain it to me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I was going to write up an answer based on the fact that temporaries will not bind to mutable references, but I just can't see why this applies here.

Answer (score 3):

Neither `f1` nor `f2` can modify their argument, `f3` however **can**. Allowing a function that was bound to `f3` to be called through `f1` or `f2` would either break const-correctness or allow to change a temporary and thus break semantical correctness.

How the implementation guarantees that these are not broken is secondary. The behaviour you describe must not work.

Comment: I was going to comment along these lines, but I suppose it's worthwhile as an answer too.

Answer (score 2):

`std::function` uses `std::forward` to pass parameters from its `operator()` to its underlying callable.  That is, an abbreviated version of `std::function` looks something like this:

```
template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
class function
{
public:
    Ret operator()(Args... args)
    {
        return get_callable()(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    // Other stuff
};
```

That means that any parameters that are non-reference types will be passed to the underlying callable as rvalues.  References to non-const cannot bind to rvalues, and so a `std::function<void(Foo)>` is incompatible with `std::function<void(Foo&)>`, but it is compatible with both `std::function<void(Foo const&)>` and `std::function<void(Foo&&)>`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I couldn't understand this part of the answer:
"That means that any parameters that are non-reference types will be passed to the underlying callable as rvalues.".
Why will parameters get passed as rvalues?

Comment: @DarkLight Because, for any non-reference type `T`, `std::forward<T>` is equivalent to `std::move`.